# Manipulating dates Momentjs in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, momentjs

I have a basic ES6 react app and am trying to use momentJS to manipulate some dates. For some reason I keep getting `month.add is not a function`

Currently the code I have is this:

```
export default class CalendarApp extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        currentDate: Moment().format(),
        month: Moment().format('MMMM'),
        year: Moment().format('YYYY')
    }

    // Bind Methods to this
    this.previousMonth = this.previousMonth.bind(this);
    this.nextMonth = this.nextMonth.bind(this);
}

previousMonth() {
    let month = this.state.month;
    month.add(-1, 'months');
    this.setState({
        month: month
    })
}

nextMonth() {
    let month = this.state.month;
    month.add(1, 'months');
    this.setState({
        month: month
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="calendar">
            <div className="calendar-container" style={ hideCalendar }>
                <caption>
                    <button className="previous-month" onClick={ this.previousMonth }>Prev</button>
                    <button className="next-month" onClick={ this.nextMonth }>Next</button> 
                    <div className="calendar-month">
                        <span>{ this.state.month } { this.state.year }</span>
                    </div>
                </caption>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I have tried various versions of setting the initial state using `Moment().month()` etc but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `.format()` you are turning it into a string, it's no longer a momentJS object.

```
moment().add(1, 'months') // A moment object

moment().add(1, 'months').subtract(6, 'days') // Can still manipulate

moment().add(1, 'months').subtract(6, 'days').format() // A final string, can't call moment funcs on it
```

Also there's no need to create multiple objects if they're all using the same time -

```
const momentNow = Moment();

this.state = {
  currentDate: momentNow.format(),
  month: momentNow.format('MMMM'),
  year: momentNow.format('YYYY')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I am only creating 1 object in state, for example currentDate, would it be possible to then later use `this.state.currentDate.format("MMMM")`?

Comment: Yep you can, although the current time is probably taken at the point of creating the object rather than when you do a .format on it - probably not an issue but worth bearing in mind

Answer (score 2):

Your state.month is a string.  That's causing the issue.

Try this

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        currentDate: Moment(),
        month: Moment().format('MMMM'),
        year: Moment().format('YYYY')
    }

    // Bind Methods to this
    this.previousMonth = this.previousMonth.bind(this);
    this.nextMonth = this.nextMonth.bind(this);
}

previousMonth() {
    let date = this.state.currentDate;
    date.add(-1, 'months');
    this.setState({
        currentDate: date,
        month: date.format('MMMM'),
        year: date.format('YYYY')
    });
}

nextMonth() {
    let date = this.state.currentDate;
    date.add(1, 'months');
    this.setState({
        currentDate: date,
        month: date.format('MMMM'),
        year: date.format('YYYY')
    });
}
```